# How to figure out whether a number is congruent in ruby?

Tags: ruby, math

I came across this snippet online while researching for ways to test that a number is a perfect square:

*if n is a perfect square then it is congruent to 0, 1 or 2 mod 4*

I tried translating it to ruby code with a ternary statement (see below) but it doesn't work correctly.

```
n % 4 == 0 && n % 4 == 1 && n % 4 == 2 ? true : false
```

How would you approach this?

Comment: good answers below, and also you should note that you used && (AND) and not || (OR) .... n%4 ==0 && n%4==1 is always WRONG (it can be 0 and 1 at the same time), while n%4 == 0 || n%4 == 1 is ok.

Comment: Yes. I noted. My first version actually used ORs. Not understanding modular arithmetic at all played a hand there.

Comment: another advice: use parenthesis unless you are really certain of operator precedence. Also, no need t use the ternary operator ? with true or false as the input of the operator is already true or false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your snipped says "*... is congruent to 0, 1 **or** 2 mod 4"* but you're using `&&`. Changing that to `||` fixes your expression:

```
n % 4 == 0 || n % 4 == 1 || n % 4 == 2 ? true : false
```

The ternary statement is redundant because you already have a boolean result. It's equivalent to:

```
n % 4 == 0 || n % 4 == 1 || n % 4 == 2
```

Furthermore `n % 4` returns either `0`, `1`, `2` or `3` for any `n`, so it can also be expressed as:

```
n % 4 <= 2  # because 0, 1, 2 are less or equal to 2
n % 4 < 3   # because 0, 1, 2 are less than 3 
n % 4 != 3  # because 0, 1, 2 are not 3
```

Comment: Whoa! Thank you. That answer is quite complete and it allowed me to better understand the multiple problems in my approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can write this:

```
n % 4 <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can approach by the following way

```
n % 4 < = 2
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
(0..2).include?(n % 4)
```